# Driving a 12-to-24 V P-channel MOSFET with TTL

Tags: mosfet, ttl, p-channel

I'd like to control up to 16 motorized valves with an ESP32. I'm using 74HCT595 shift registers (5 V outputs, 3.3 V input logic) to drive 12 V relays via NPN transistors. But the relays are pretty overkill and I'd like to replace them with MOSFETs. Since the motor valves need a switched +12V line, I need high side switching. In addition, I'd like to design the circuit so I can optionally switch to 24 V valves later without changing the circuit/PCB. I found this circuit on [image: forum.arduino.cc] (https://forum.arduino.cc/t/protect-p-channel-mosfet-from-high-vgs-with-a-zener-diode/328512/6) which uses a 10 V Zener diode across gate-source and a 200 Ω resistor between the emitter and ground of the NPN BJT. Although it says 12 V VCC, the original author meant it to be for 24 V.

I have 2 problems with the circuit:

1. Shouldn’t the 200 Ω resistor be between collector and gate of the MOSFET, otherwise a 5 V voltage between GND and base won't turn on the BJT?
2. Isn’t the 200 Ω resistor smaller and will burn more energy than necessary? The Mosfet doesnt need much current, won't a 1k or even higher be fine too?
3. Will this circuit be fine, without changing values, for both 12 V and 24 V VCC?

I made a suggestion of my own: [image: 12-24V with LED] with R1 moved and larger - will this work as intended? Note I don't have a resistor across the Zener diode, do I need one with the LED there? I won't have any rapid switching so I don't mind if it takes a few ms for the MOSFET to turn off.

Comment: A motorized valve uses normally 3 connections, +12V, GND1 and GND2. Can you tell me the product number of your valve? The 12V-contact is hard connected to 12V, the other two GND-contacts are there for left drive and for right drive of the internal motor. Opening and closing of the valve. So you only need a transistor for each direction (closing and opening) and a free running diode from each Drain to +12V.

Comment: @MikroPower I've never seen valves with one constant +12V and alternate switched GND pins. Mine have fixed GND, a fixed +12V, and a switched +12V (on=position A, off = position B).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldnt the 200Ohm resistor be between collector and gate of the MOSFET, otherwise a 5V voltage between GND and base won't turn on the BJT?

R1, the 200Ω resistor is there to limit zener diode current while it is clamping \$V_{GS}\$. It does prevent Q1's collector from ever reaching all the way down to 0V, but it can still get far enough away from the positive supply to fully switch on Q2.

Your claim that this will require a higher base potential to turn Q1 on is correct, but emitter resistor R1 is modifying Q1's behaviour somewhat. It permits the emitter to rise in potential above 0V, which wouldn't be possible if the emitter were tied directly to ground.

Without going deep into the algebra, imagine that Q1 were saturated, and the emitter and collector were effectively connected together. Then R2 and R1 form a potential divider between +12V and ground, with \$12V \times \frac{200}{1000+200}=2V\$ in the middle (emitter & collector). To achieve that Q1 would require \$2V+V_{BE}=2.7V\$ at its base.

In other words, saturation occurs for inputs over +2.7V, which is fine. However, collector potential cannot ever drop below 2V, but that is still sufficiently low to turn on Q2.

For \$ V_{BASE}<+2.7V\$, base current will be very small, since the Q1 isn't saturated yet, and almost all current in R1 will come via the collector. Above +2.7V input, though, Q1 is saturated, and the base-emitter junction will tend to lift emitter potential with it. Extra current required to do this must come via the base; with a +5V input you can expect over 11mA to be drawn from the source, a digital output of the '595.

The '595 outputs are capable of sourcing 8mA maximum, each. Whatever design you settle on must not ask for more than this.

> Isn't the 200Ohm resistor smaller and will burn more energy than necessary? The Mosfet doesnt need much current, won't a 1k or even higher be fine too?

Yes, that's correct. But driving a MOSFET is about more than just switching it on or off. It's also about doing it *fast*. Q2's gate is a capacitor that needs charging and discharging, and the smaller the resistors feeding the gate, the faster that happens. I think this is the primary motivation for the designer to have chosen such low values.

It doesn't sound like your application is particularly demanding in this respect, so I imagine you can get away with much larger resistances.

> Will this circuit be fine, without changing values, for both 12V and 24V VCC?

I doubt it. Doubling the supply voltage from 12V to 24V will nearly double the base voltage required to saturate Q1, bringing it perilously close to the +5V available from your '595.

---

Your own design is nearly perfect. I have a few suggestions:

- You really should include an additional resistor across the zener diode, to aid in switching the MOSFET off. Don't rely on the LED and its resistor to do this.
- You don't need such a small resistor at Q1's base.
- Your MOSFET is upside down. Connect source to +24V.
- Include a diode to protect the transistor from inductive loads (Edit: I just noticed you already did this, sorry).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwHz7U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Input current will be well under 1mA for each '595 output, which is perfectly acceptable.

This design will work well from a 12V or 24V supply, although current draw from the supply increases from 3mA @ 12V (no load) to 12mA @ 24V, due to zener diode D2 becoming conductive.

Comment: Thank you, especially for correcting my design suggestion. Any reason you changed the 10V Zener to 12V? I chose 10V because most Mosfets are happy with 10V Vgs, 12V might be too much for some? Also, you explained (more than I could follow ;-) ) on why the emitter resistor isnt as bad as I thought, but could you please confirm that the collector resistor solution is better in my case? Or why would one choose the emitter version in the first place - to limit current? (But if that makes the circuit non-24V tolerable, its not really an option).

Comment: @EthanArnold I chose 12V arbitrarily, I couldn't be bothered to find out what voltage those zener diodes are! You'd have to define "better" better, but in terms of 12V/24V compatibility then your own solution is definitely "better". A carefully chosen emitter resistance may improve switching speed (by keeping the transistor out of deep saturation), but the cost (as I explained) is a more constrained operating supply voltage range. Speed isn't important, so I'd still go with your own approach.

Answer (score 2):

A few comments. The 200Ω emitter resistor makes Q1 into a 15 to 20mA constant-current sink. Q1 never saturates so it switches more quickly. That doesn't matter much in this case because the only thing discharging the gate charge is the 1kΩ resistor. At 24V the transistor will get warm  because the current is the same and the voltage is higher, but it will work.

Wasting power, however, is how you get the P-channel MOSFET to switch quickly without adding the complexity of more transistors. Since it is the power component, there will be a relatively large amount of gate charge (as much as 19nC in the case of the  IPD50P04P4 and 44nC in the case of the beefier original MOSFET). If the MOSFET switches too slowly the safe operating area of the MOSFET can be violated, resulting in failure (that happens when there is substantial current flowing with substantial voltage across the MOSFET). The Miller capacitance (drain to gate) means that the drain voltage change fights the gate drive, slowing it down.

Keep in mind that there's a trade-off between the resistor values (and resulting power dissipation) and how fast the MOSFET will switch. For circuits requiring fast switching or when you are pushing the SOA margins it's better to have active drive for the gate rather than resistors.

In any case here is a comparison of the two circuits, the second one is pretty much Simon's circuit but with the FQP MOSFET in both cases, to allow comparison of the driver circuit. The load inductance is set rather low, again to allow comparison. Without the 4.7KΩ resistor to discharge the gate that Simon added, the off switching would not be good (and maybe not even sufficient to turn the MOSFET completely off, depending on the LED and MOSFET Vt). Blue trace is the input drive voltage. For high frequency switching an inductive load in the amperes, a Schottky diode should be used but it doesn't matter much here.

[image]

Off switching:
[image: ![enter image description here]

On switching:

[image]

You can see two slopes in the switching, the slower slope is where the Miller capacitance is fighting the gate drive current.

Comment: Thank you for the analysis. If I read the graphs correct, the on+off switching are both well under 10µs, which may be too slow for high frequency switching, but for my switching once a minute, and the loads will be well under the Mosfet's limits (oversized to keep them cool without heatsinks) should be fine I think? Q1 getting warm is exactly what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Yes, I think it's fine. The safe operating area and the DC power dissipation (heating) of the MOSFET are the things to check. Also keep in mind that a "brown out" can destroy the MOSFET if it doesn't get enough gate drive since this simple circuit (unlike most IC gate drivers) does not have undervoltage lockout. Up to you to decide how unlikely that is or to mitigate in some other way.